# MVC Action not getting called in Internet explorer and Mozilla firefox

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, mozilla, internet-explorer-11

**Good Day**
         In my application whenever i press browser back button i want to get data 
i am getting data in Google chrome browser it works fine 
but when i test in Inter explorer 11 and Mozilla Firefox it does not work
the action is not being called
the alert is being executed but the action is not being called
when i test in any browser whenever user presses back button alert is being fired

bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function () {

```
            alert(document.referrer);

           var url = "/Login/GetID";
                $.getJSON(
                    url,
                    null,
                    function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't really mess around with the back button in the browser. While it may be possible, not all browsers will handle it well, and it may alienate your users.

Comment: yes but i tested in the IE,Safari ,opera ,Google chrome it ,Mozilla it works fine any other way of knowing that user has pressed browser back button the My Action is not getting called in IE browser

Comment: If you tested and it works fine, what is the problem?

Comment: My Action("/Login/GetID") GetID is not getting called but alert my is getting triggered

Comment: It's probably cached or something like that. What you are trying to do is NOT a good idea and will cause you more trouble in the long run.

Comment: Any other way of finding whether user has pressed browser back button basically what i want is  .when the user logs in comes to the next page(home page say) and then again presses browser back button then log in screen will come then again if he presses browser back button this will bring him to the home page without logging in which is false i want o clear the sessions

Comment: Other way of doing this  in global file add this event but i don't to use this                                            protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code disables caching by browser. Hence the back browser button          
            
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();                                 }

Comment: Who cares if the user presses back and goes to the login page? That is what SHOULD happen and what a user would EXPECT to happen.

Comment: :) I know but i have to do it

Comment: Then remind me to never visit one of your websites :)

Comment: :) why is my action not being called it not working in IE and Mozilla rest in Google chrome ,safari ,opera it works fine where my i going wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent that behavior either by adding "cache: false" to every call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```